# What does this mean: int (*arr)[2]?

Tags: c, pointers

I know that the following would be an array of two elements each holding a pointer to an integer:

```
int* arr[2];
```

But I don't really understand what this does:

```
int (*arr)[2];
```

This is from the video course on data structures I'm watching right now, but I don't find the lecturer's explanation as to how exactly you should understand this kind of syntax all that clear, to say the least. Here's the YouTube link: [Lecture 16: Dynamic Allocation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69OzAUm_Mp0&list=PLgj_V-ZKxRKrxgFyOutPJpoLFBaQMOpK-&index=16#t=21m40s) (just click on the link and it will automatically take you to the moment he talks about it)

Comment: Pointer to an array of 2 `int`s.

Comment: I see now. This looks similar to how we declare function pointers.

Comment: Do a favor to your self, do not watch that video again.

Comment: haccks, Why is that?

Comment: Because 1) `a` is that video is an array not a pointer as he claims. 2) He is casting the value of `malloc` which is a bad practice. 3) He makes the explanation too complex for beginners and finally 4) He doesn't seem to be updated.